# VSTS Dashboard Access with Personal Access Token

Tags: azure-devops, dashboard, azure-devops-rest-api

Is it possible to access a dashboard in VSTS using a personal access token? I would like to display the dashboard on a wall-mounted TV without having to log into VSTS every time.

Answer (score 0):

A Personal Access Token cannot be used for logging in to the Web UI. PATs are used for accessing REST APIs or Git repositories from external tools.

As a workaround you could create a dummy Stakeholder account. Those are free and have permission to view the dashboard. You can then use that account on your TV.

Comment: This would work, but would require someone to plug a keyboard and mouse into the TV and log in again every few days, so not a great solution.

Comment: @CyberJacob why do you have to do this every few days? Why do you think that would be different with a PAT?

Comment: logins expire after ~1 week IIRC, whereas a PAT could be used to load the dashboard with no user interaction for 2 years (the maximum term of them)

Comment: @CyberJacob did you manage to get a solution to this problem?

Comment: @ciaranj Unfortunately not, I ended up using Selenium to automate the logon process.

Comment: @CyberJacob oh no, bad times! ;)